# AppStore API for search and download?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, python

I am looking for an AppStore API, official or 3rd party, that would enable me to both search for (using keywords) and download apps. I'd be downloading free apps, such as:

- https://itunes.apple.com/app/angry-birds-2/id880047117

There is a 3rd party [Google Play Unofficial Python API](https://github.com/NoMore201/googleplay-api) available, but does such a thing (preferably in Python) exist for the AppStore?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official API to search the App Store. Also, starting with iTunes 12.7, Apple has removed the ability to browse, search for and download iOS apps on a Mac or a PC.

Currently, the only official way for public users to download and install iOS apps is directly on a device via the App Store app. This was done as a measure towards optimizing the installed app's bundle size depending on device type and capabilities.

There is an official iTunes Search API (with very limited support for apps) which you can check here:

- [iTunes Affiliate Resources](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the link you have provided, the `software` portion of the `entity` row, it only states that there are `software, iPadSoftware, macSoftware` which effectively rules out the presence of the general iOS API.

Comment: Replying to a very old comment, but "software" means "iPhone apps" in that API.